# Tracking/Checking in on a MKMapView

Tags: ios, gps, maps

I have seen on an application before called Trip Journal you can track or check into the places you have been and displays this on a map. I was wondering if anyone knows the code and process of this or knows of a tutorial?

Similar to Trip Journal, I want the user to be able to check into their destinations and have the map remember the destinations and join the destinations together.

Thanks

Comment: Follow MKMAPKit Tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Code and introduction is given in Apple's Location Awareness Guide.